# Filter the input of another input with unknown length in R Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, purrr

The users can select some variables of `mtcars`, after they select those variables, they continue selecting the levels of each variable. At the end, how I can return the filter data after they select levels of each variable

`dt <- reactive({data <- dt %>% filter(.....)  %>% filter(.....) ....and so on})`, how I can use %>% to loop through or map to filter the data?

I appreciate your time.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Example"),
  uiOutput("var"),
  uiOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dt <- mtcars[, c(2, 8:11)]
  dt[] <- lapply(dt, factor)
  
  output$var <- renderUI({
    selectInput("var", "Select Variable", choices = names(dt), multiple = T)
  })
  
 level <- reactive({
   choice <- select(dt, input$var)
   print(choice)
 })
  
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq_along(input$var), function(i) {
      selectInput(paste0("level",i), paste0("Select Levels of ", input$var[[i]]), choices =  unique(level()[[i]]), multiple = T)
    })
  })
  
  dt <- reactive({
   data <- dt %>% filter(.....)  %>% filter(.....) ....and so on
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved via `purrr::reduce`. Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Example"),
  uiOutput("var"),
  uiOutput("test"),
  tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dt <- mtcars[, c(2, 8:11)]
  dt[] <- lapply(dt, factor)
  
  output$var <- renderUI({
    selectInput("var", "Select Variable", choices = names(dt), multiple = T)
  })
  
  level <- reactive({
    choice <- select(dt, input$var)
    print(choice)
  })
  
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq_along(input$var), function(i) {
      selectInput(paste0("level", i), paste0("Select Levels of ", input$var[[i]]), choices =  unique(level()[[i]]), multiple = T)
    })
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    purrr::reduce(seq_along(input$var), ~ filter(.x, !!sym(input$var[[.y]]) %in% input[[paste0("level", .y)]]), .init = dt)
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've just learned from the new [shiny book](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html) that there is an alternative to `!!sym(input$var[[.y]])`, you can also use `.data[[input$var[[.y]]]]` (as they do in the book). Not sure if this is more concise here though