# Filter dataset based on dynamic number of user inputs from user file upload

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, purrr

I am making a shiny app where the user should be able to upload a file then filter the dataset based on the unique values (levels) of all character columns in the uploaded file. I am able to dynamically generate the correct `pickerInput` (`selectInput`) elements, but am having trouble executing the filtering. I used the link below as a guide but am having trouble figuring out how to get the selected values (I think `input[[paste0("level", .y)]]` is where my problem is).

[Filter the input of another input with unknown length in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103674/filter-the-input-of-another-input-with-unknown-length-in-r-shiny)

Input CSV file

```
structure(list(factorGroup1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), factorGroup2 = c("D", "D", "E", 
"E", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E"), factorGroup3 = c("F", 
"G", "F", "G", "F", "G", "F", "G", "F", "G", "F", "G"), numVar = c(5L, 
8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

App code

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("fileIn", 
              "Load input file",
              multiple = F)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("generateFilters"),
    tableOutput("dataOut")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  getData <- reactive({
    req(input$fileIn)
    dataIn <- as.data.frame(fread(input$fileIn$datapath))
    return(dataIn)
  })
  
  output$generateFilters <- renderUI({
    lapply(names(Filter(is.character, getData())), function(i) {
      
      filterLevels <- unique(getData()[,i])
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(inputId = paste(i),
                                label = paste(i),
                                choices = filterLevels,
                                multiple = T,
                                options = list(`actions-box` = T),
                                selected = filterLevels)
    })
  })
  
  dataFxn <- reactive({
    purrr::reduce(seq_along(input$generateFilters), 
                  ~ filter(.x, .data[[ input$generateFilters[[.y]] ]] %in% 
                             input[[paste0("level", .y)]]), 
                  .init = getData())
  })
  
  output$dataOut <- renderTable({
    dataFxn()
  })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try with `.data[[ input$generateFilters[[.y]] ]]`.

Comment: My mistake, fixed in code above but unfortunately does not fix the filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the post you referenced had a slightly different logic and used some bad notation, i.e. there was both an `input` named `var` and an `output` named `var`. To make the solution from the answer work for your case requires some adjustments, i.e. for `reduce` we have to loop over `names(Filter(is.character, getData()))` as in `lapply` and inside the function we have to do `filter(.x, .data[[ .y ]] %in% input[[.y]])` to filter the data.

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("fileIn",
      "Load input file",
      multiple = F
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("generateFilters"),
    tableOutput("dataOut")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  getData <- reactive({
   dataIn
  })

  output$generateFilters <- renderUI({
    lapply(names(Filter(is.character, getData())), function(i) {
      filterLevels <- unique(getData()[, i])
      shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
        inputId = paste(i),
        label = paste(i),
        choices = filterLevels,
        multiple = T,
        options = list(`actions-box` = T),
        selected = filterLevels
      )
    })
  })

  dataFxn <- reactive({
    purrr::reduce(names(Filter(is.character, getData())), function(.x, .y) {
      filter(.x, .data[[ .y ]] %in% input[[.y]])  
    },
      .init = getData()
    )
  })

  output$dataOut <- renderTable({
    dataFxn()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thanks a lot for your examples, I learned a lot. Almost got there with your original example by re-coding the `generateFilters` `inputId`s to numbers and keeping `seq_along` but this way makes much more sense.